# How do I insert value into dataset at runtime using microsoft SQL server in vb.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

this is the code I am using for trying to insert a row to my dataset.
It executes properly till sqlConnection is opened. But the nonQuery execution throws a 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' I believe there is something wrong with my connection string, I copied it from the app./config file and I cannot figure out what is wrong. Also, I know I should use a parameterized SQL query, I will implement that later.

```
    Dim sqlConnection1 As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalD;Initial Catalog=ContactInfo;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False")
    Dim cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Table (ID, FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, Type, Telephone, Extension, Email) VALUES (" + row.ID.ToString + "," + "'" + row.FirstName + "'" + "," + "'" + row.MiddleName + "'" + "," + "'" + row.LastName + "'" + "," + "'" + row.Type + "'" + "," + row.Telephone.ToString + "," + "'" + row.Extension + "'" + "," + "'" + row.Email + "')"
    cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1
    sqlConnection1.Open()
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    sqlConnection1.Close()
```

Comment: Post full error exception

Comment: The first MAJOR problem I see here is that your code is wide open to sql injection. You need to read about, understand and start using parameterized queries. DO NOT fall into the trap of "I will fix it later". The reality is that you won't actually ever do it. Just learn how to do it correctly the first time. It doesn't take any more time once you learn how. As to the problem at hand....well unless you tell us the error message we have to guess.

Comment: First law of programming: _"I will implement that later"_  - equals - "will never happen" . If some of the values contains `'` character you will get `SqlException` - so again use `SqlParameter` and you will save your  time.  And use `&` character for concatenate strings in `vb.net`. If you write `Option Strict On` on the first line of your code file - you will get more help from compiler in finding possible errors.

Answer (score 0):

First, Don't think that you can name your table "Table" so change it to your real table name and it should run 
And USE SQL PARAMETERS!

Second, get the result of ExecuteNonQuery to a variable so you can check, if a record was written or not.